# transfer wbnb from contract to metamask

Tags: solidity, transfer, binance-smart-chain, bot

i transferred wbnb from my deployed contract to metamask using python. The transaction was not executed. However, when checking later the wbnb balance of my contract was 0, my wbnb was stolen. i have a custom function to transfer my wbnb's but they were still stolen. What could have happened? I do not have approved permissions, nor connected websites.

wrong transaction: https://bscscan.com/tx/0xce1232d3b446667fff78dede3adcc2453c34ef577bb98e668bf25b2d10d42e3b

transaction that stole my wbnb:
https://bscscan.com/tx/0xbbbe070414c875052a80d6e7cb382d6357ee5fe978f0fddb2427acf37fdbbdfb

my code:

```
    // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
    pragma solidity >=0.6.6 <0.8.0;
    
    
    interface IUniswapV2Pair {
        event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint value);
        event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint value);
        function transfer(address to, uint value) external returns (bool);
        function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint value) external returns (bool);
    }
    interface IERC20 {
        /**
         * @dev Returns the amount of tokens in existence.
         */
        function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
        /**
         * @dev Returns the remaining number of tokens that `spender` will be
         * allowed to spend on behalf of `owner` through {transferFrom}. This is
         * zero by default.
         *
         * This value changes when {approve} or {transferFrom} are called.
         */
        event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
        event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
    }
    
    
     contract Flashswap {
        address public owner;
        address private wbnb;
      
        constructor() {
            owner = msg.sender;  
            wbnb = 0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c;
            }
    
        function transfer_bnb_to_wallet(uint256 _amount, address _dest) external{
            IERC20(wbnb).transfer(_dest,_amount);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `transfer_bnb_to_wallet` doesn't have any protection. Anyone can call it and use their own address as the recipient

```
function transfer_bnb_to_wallet(uint256 _amount, address _dest) external{
    IERC20(wbnb).transfer(_dest,_amount);
}
```

The function could have been made `onlyOwner` so only the owner can call it.

It doesn't matter the contract isn't verified. There are bots that inspect the pending pool for transaction that they can exploit.

The attacker used a higher gas price so miners picked it before than your transaction.